# Why is pgAdmin using port 1?

Tags: sql, postgresql, localhost, port, pgadmin

Still new to postgres and programming in general. On my laptop pgAdmin works fine, but when I installed it the the exact same way on my desktop I run into an issue where the application runs on the localhost with port 1, which causes Chrome to throw a "unsafe port" error.

[Here is how chrome runs pgAdmin that causes unsafe port erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrdJ2.png)

[Here is the error chrome gives because pgAdmin runs off port 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NppmF.png)

The only way I have been able to get around this is by adding --explicitly-allowed-ports=1 in chrome properties. However, I am not sure if this is safe to do so.

How do I get pgAdmin to use a port that is not blocked by chrome? Thank you for any help!

Comment: 5432 is the port PostgreSQL itself uses, which is different from the port pgAdmin's HTTP server uses.

Comment: Do you know how I can change it so that pgAdmin does not use port 1?

Comment: In your pgAdmin's `config_local.py`, you can set `DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT` to a value of your choosing. If you're running pgAdmin behind some other kind of server, you'll have to consult that server's documentation on how to change the port.

Comment: There is not a config_local.py in the web directory. There is a config.py and a config_distro.py. Does this mean that I will need to create a config_local.py file?

Comment: As documented [here](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/config_py.html), that seems to be the way to go.

"config_local.py: This file is read after config_distro.py and is intended for end users to change any default or packaging specific settings that they may wish to adjust to meet local preferences or standards.This file is optional, and may be created by users in the same directory as config.py if needed."

Please excuse the formatting, comments don't really give much liberty.